# How to add timestamp to filename in UFT when using writetofile property

Tags: hp-uft, web-api-testing, servicetestcase

I trying to generate files with time stamp when I'm running test with multiple inputs(parameterisation).

Please suggest me how to add timestamp to filename
ex: `C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Responses\xxx.xlsx` to this path I need to append timestamp to make file unique .

Comment: Could you post your code? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Easy option:

```
Dim sTimeStamp, sPath
sPath = "C:\Path\To\My\Folder\myFile.xlsx"

' Get current time and date value and strip out the separators
sTimeStamp = Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, " ", "_"), "/", ""), ":", "")

'insert timestamp into file name
sPath = Replace(sPath, ".xlsx", "_" & sTimeStamp & ".xlsx")

Debug.Write sPath ' output is C:\Path\To\My\Folder\myFile_20112017_015827.xlsx
```